# SSL Error when trying to query to db with mysql-connector and flask

Tags: python, mysql

I've been trying to work with flask in python. I have a mysql connection using mysql-connection-python. The problem I'm having is when I make a request from the browser (XMLHttpRequest) I get this error
`mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'remotemysql.com:3306', system error: 1 [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2622)`
I have no ideia how to fix this.

I'm using `http://localhost:5000/...`

Comment: what's in the mysql settings ? probably mysql have SSL enabled.

Comment: @farbiondriven this is a remote mysql from a website I got just for testing. I believe I can't change those settings. Is there a workaround for it? Does enabling ssl in flask fix the issue? Because I tried adding `ssl_context='adhoc'` in `app.run()`, changed every request to https and still throws the same error

Comment: I suggest you play with a local mysql if you just want to play. To play with that remote DB, you might need to get some certificates. Have a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html

Comment: I have the same question, however, the remote database engine is mine, it has SSL configured correctly because I can access from the engine's host (localhost), but I'm trying access it from a different host using the same client credentials.